How to create a async set state in reactjs?
Have a project with ReactJS using classes, like as:
import { Component } from 'react';

class FooComponent extends Component {

    async setStateAsync(data) {
        return (new Promise(resolve => this.setState(data, resolve)));
    }

    async login() {
        // Preparing UI with loader
        return this.setStateAsync({
            sending: true,
            badCredentials: null
        })
        .then(AuthService.login(...))
        .then(...)
        .then(foo => this.setState({ foo: foo }))
        .then(...)
        .catch(e => this.setState({
            sending: false,
            badCredentials: e
        }))
    }
}

Why not use two setState in same function?, reactJS have problems to keep the context in async functions, the first set state chane the html content but is async, but the function is not async, require a finish callback, can not wait the results to continue in inline mode, for resolve this i made a async setstate and works fine when use multiple times the asyncState in same function.
I try set the function as global into Component class, from index.js:
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import App from './app';

// Set a async state function
Component.prototype.setStateAsync = async (data) =>
    (new Promise(resolve => this.setState(data, resolve)));

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();

But does not work, the setState function is not found when initialize the Component class, the this object is not a instance of the new classs.
How to access to current setState instance of the initialized class or set the async function as global for Componen?

Very good idea, it's a shame that ReactJS doesn't have a promise-based asynchronous function to create a chain of promises.
Your problem is based on a bug in the javascript implementation which does not allow using lambda syntax in prototype definitions, to solve this you must change the lambda function style to traditional:
Component.prototype.setStateAsync = async function(data){
    return new Promise(resolve => this.setState(data, resolve));
}

